# PHP via CLI throws error however works fine from browser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, command-line-interface

This particular PHP file works perfectly when executed via the browser. However, I'd like it to run on task scheduler in Windows so I set the scheduler to launch php.exe and point it to the correct file.

Task scheduler is basically doing the same thing as if I type it directly into the CLI I believe. Now, it seems to have worked a few times but now it repeatedly fails even when I manually call the task via CLI.

The relevant code is:

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$results = ....Some CURL Commands to retrieve data....
$html = str_get_html($results);
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr)
{   
    ....do stuff....
}
```

In CLI it says

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\php\report.php on line...
```

Why does CLI find fault here and browser does not? Again, this has worked once or twice on CLI so it might some kind of time-out setting.

Comment: I have a feeling this could be a permissions issue with the simple_htm_dom.php file

Comment: Maybe it cannot find included file?

Comment: Perhaps the curl-commands fail and $html is empty? Can you output $html?

Comment: I don't think the curl commands fail because then it would throw an error regarding curl. If the curl is failing, why does it only fail via CLI and never via browser?

Comment: It would be better on CLI to debug the curl result, just to discard that problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the  script on CLI, did you check if file_get_html() is returning FALSE?

If that is the case, maybe the script can't reach the resource from the terminal using curl for some reason (e.g.: proxy settings).

Make sure to check that case on what you get from that function with something like:

```
$html = str_get_html($results);

if ($html !== FALSE) {
  // treat the success case.
}
```

Comment: hmm. You're correct that the curl data was not coming in. I think I figured it out though

Answer (score 0):

All your answers led me to figure out the problem. I investigated the permissions angle but that didn't solve it. There is another 'include' file I have called common_functions.php which I also include. Permissions on that also didn't solve the problem.

However, the curl function is actually located in common_functions. Upon investigating that file, it contains references to cookies.txt where the path was not absolute. I had not setup my environment variables correctly so CLI could not find the cookie which made the Curl function fail.....I corrected and it works now.

Lesson learned. Thank you all for the clues you provided.